# Jackson: need a another method to be a setter

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
public class UrlTemplate extends AbstractBeanDefinition implements Serializable {

    private List<HeaderField> header = new ArrayList<>();

    @Tag("header")
    public List<HeaderField> getHeader() {
        return this.header;
    }

    @Node("header/header-field")
    public void setHeader(HeaderField headerField) {
        this.header.add(headerField);
    }

    public void setHeader(List<HeaderField> header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

`Tag` and `Node` annotation are used by other library, and I can't change method `setHeader(HeaderField headerField)`.

I define a valid setter `setHeader(List<HeaderField> header)` for serializing, but when I try to serialize `UrlTemplate` to String and deserialize String to `UrlTemplate`, throw exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Conflicting setter definitions for property "header": 
com.enniu.crawler.encreeper.core.domain.config.search.UrlTemplate#setHeader(1 params) vs 
com.enniu.crawler.encreeper.core.domain.config.search.UrlTemplate#setHeader(1 params)
```

I think I may declare `setHeader(List<HeaderField> header)` to be the setter that Jackson take to deserialize, but I have no idea about how to do it with the Jackson.

Could any one give me some hint?

Comment: Does marking one of the setters explicitly with `@JsonProperty("header")` solve the problem? If it doesn't, you might also need to `@JsonIgnore` the other setter (the one you don't want to use for JSON).

Comment: @dhke Thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JsonProperty` annotation from jackson

```
@JsonProperty("header")
private Object headerJson;

public Object getHeaderJson() {
    return status;
}

public void setHeaderJson(Object headerJson) {
    this.headerJson= headerJson;
}
```

`headerJson` will be mapped to json `header` so it should resolve the conflict issue.